# How to draw a tangent line to a curve fit?

Tags: curve-fitting

I fitted my stress-strain data with cubic fits as shown in the figure below and added the corresponding straight lines (dashed and same color). The problem is I put these straight lines at my own discretion by means of visual inspection. So of course if someone else tries to add these tangent straight lines, that would differ. I am wondering if there is a way to put tangent lines in a deterministic way allowing the "reproduceability". Thanks.

[image]

Comment: So you have a fitted curve ($\hat{g}(x)$), and you want to draw a tangent line at some known point, $x^*$?

Comment: orthopolis - I still mean to come back with an answer on your previous question, but it's involved and I've been waiting for a chink of time to write a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me talk about the general case:

You have a fitted curve ($\hat{g}(x)$), and you want to draw a tangent line at some known point, $x^*$?

The slope at $x^*$ is $b=\frac{d}{dx}\hat{g}(x)|_{x=x^*} = \hat{g}'(x^*)$.

The value of the function at $x^*$ is $y^* = \hat{g}(x^*)$.

So you want a line through the point $(x^*,y^*)$ with slope $b$.

That  is, $\frac{y-y^*}{x-x^*}=b$. Rearranging, $y=y^*+b(x-x^*)=(y^*-bx^*)+bx=a+bx$.

That is, the line  has slope $b=\hat{g}'(x^*)$ and intercept $a=(y^*-bx^*)=\hat{g}(x^*)-\hat{g}'(x^*)x^*$.

---

The problem is figuring out what $x$-value you want to draw the tangent line *at*, rather than drawing the tangent line itself.

The point at which a cubic is "linear" (the point of inflexion) occurs when the second derivative is zero. One can only presume that's where you want to draw your tangent.

So you work out the second derivative of the fitted cubic (which is linear) and solve to find the $x$ at which it's zero.

So if the fitted cubic is of the form $a + bx + cx^2+dx^3$, its second derivative is $2c+6dx$ which is zero when $x=-\frac{c}{3d}$.

Comment: In some sense this is a change-point problem whose purpose is to identify when a trend transitions from linear to something else. But basing the analysis on derivatives is problematic, because if they are computed naively (via differences of the data) they will be highly variable and if they are computed from a fitted curve they might be sensitive to the fitting procedure. Therefore I believe it would be more productive to approach the problem differently, without using derivatives directly. Ideally, the analysis should use a theoretical model as a point of departure.

Comment: @whuber I was certainly assuming a model, not numeric derivatives. The OP doesn't seem to have a theoretical model for the problem, though I am sure there are theoretical models for this. [I'm not really in a position to give the specific subject area advice - at least not without researching it myself, which I think goes beyond the scope of what's usually to be expected (we can't be chemists and physicists and biologists and astronomers and geologists and psychologists and economists and actuaries and linguists and ... ).

Comment: Thanks Glen for your kind effort to find an answer to my question. Although I am giving up but your explanation followed by others' comment helped me a lot and would others as well.

Comment: orthopolis - I think the biggest problem has been one of us not quite communicating to each other clearly, which leads to us trying to solve a slightly different problem to the one you actually have (but which I am still not clear on).